# ngUpgrade and Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm starting a new project and thinking to the future. 
I know that both frameworks (Angular1 & Angular2) can cohabit with the ngUpgrade library and even use Angular2 component within Angular1. 
 
Is it possible to use ngUpgrade with Ionic v1?
 If yes, how?
If someone has a starter template, a tutorial or anything else, I take!

Comment: If you're starting a new project, why not start it purely with Angular 2 (and Ionic 2)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ionic 2 is currently in alpha. It's not for production use but only for testing purposes.

Comment: It's actually in beta. Same as Angular 2.

Comment: Only ionic-cli is in beta. The framework is still in alpha. You can look at the package.json. You will see "ionic-framework": "2.0.0-alpha.45"